# requirejs define modules accessible from all context

Tags: javascript, requirejs

My problem is the following. I'm using different context (require.js ones) to load some widgets as there have different baseUrl. Each widget need some commons modules like text plugin or css plugin so currently I need to define them into the require config through the paths object. But in this case, each plugin will be loaded each time you require a widget as they belong to different context while they are actually the same.

To be more clear, here an example:

```
app1_require = require.config({context:'app1',baseUrl:'/app1',paths:{text:'../text'}})
app2_require = require.config({context:'app2',baseUrl:'/app2',paths:{text:'../text'}})
```

In using app1_require then app2_require, I will have the plugin text injected twice into the DOM (two script tag). How can I proceed to set the text module as a global one which can be used within all contexts? Note that I'm also using a require without any context to load some global dependencies.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: I've found a solution which consist in cloning directy the module from the global context to all specific contexts before require anything (require.s.contexts[app_name].defined[mod] = require.s.contexts._.defined[mod]).

Comment: I've been looking for a solution for this same problem, and cloning the context's `defined` array is the only good option I see.

Comment: It may still be necessary to copy over path settings, which can be done like so:  `myContext = require.config({
        context: 'mycontext',
        paths: require.s.contexts._.config.paths
    });`

A separate `config()` call me then be necessary to set up any additional paths